# Prevent animation from scrolling to top when Fragment is popped

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation, android-scrollview

I have a fragment with a `RecyclerView`, and if the `RecyclerView` has more than a certain number of items, I increase the height of the root layout so that I can scroll down (I know `RecyclerView` can scroll on its own, I wanted to scroll the whole layout). Now, if I press back after I scroll to the bottom, the pop back animation I set occurs, as usual:

```
<!-- slide_out_right.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="250" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="250" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"/>
</set>
```

However, this animation causes the fragment to scroll to top before disappearing. At first I thought this was due to the `ScrollView` I wrap around the `FrameLayout` I am using for placing fragments; however, this issue was gone when I disabled the fragment animations. I have played around with the XML file for the custom animation, but could not prevent it from scrolling to top. Is there a way to do this so that the "fragment view state" does not change before the animation?

*Note:* I have tried the `android:fillAfter` and `android:fillBefore` attributes, but they did not help.

**EDIT**:

*Where I set the custom transitions:*

```
// ITEM FRAGMENT
public void launchItemFragment(String itemId, String itemName, ActivityDetail activityDetail) {
  if (mItemFrag == null) {
     mItemFrag = new ItemFragment(); //ItemFragment.newInstance(itemId, itemName, activityDetail);
  }
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("itemId", itemId);
  bundle.putString("itemName", itemName);
  bundle.putParcelable("activityDetail", activityDetail);
  mItemFrag.setArguments(bundle);
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right_scroll);
  ft.replace(R.id.main_container, mItemFrag, "fragment_item").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

*Handling back presses:* I `popBackStack()` if `getBackStackEntryCount() > 0`.

*MainActivity relevant layout section (root layout is ConstraintLayout):*

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:overScrollMode="never"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_cart_right"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_main_right"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_top_nav_bottom"
  tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
  tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
  tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
  tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">
  <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/main_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/MainFragStyle"/>
</ScrollView>
```

*Layout xml of the fragment in question*:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                         android:id="@+id/root_fragment_item"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:id="@+id/header_section_background"
  android:background="@color/colorItemHeaderBackground"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<View
  android:id="@+id/header_section_triangle"
  android:layout_width="40dp"
  android:layout_height="22dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  android:background="@drawable/triangle"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/header_item_title"
  style="@style/ItemHeaderTitle"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
  android:text="Title"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"/>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/header_item_duration"
  style="@style/ItemHeaderSubtitle"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
  android:text="Duration"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/item_details"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  android:overScrollMode="never"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
  android:id="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="172dp"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*How I resize the layout (will maybe help):*

```
if (mItemDetails.size() > 6) {
     DisplayMetrics dm = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
     float toolbarPx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, dm);
     float height = dm.heightPixels - toolbarPx;
     mConstraintLayout.getLayoutParams().height = Math.round(height) + Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50*(mItemDetails.size()-6), dm));
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you execute the animation? maybe the whole fragment class, this way it's easier for us to replicate the issue.

Comment: @MateusGondim edited my original post to have more details